# Paho MQTT Client Publication / Disconnect Sequence

Tags: java, mqtt, iot, paho

I am confused by the programming model of mqtt.
My goal is to deploy a client that periodically retrieves sensor data
 and publish them on a topic via mqtt paho client.

In the code-examples from paho after every publication they disconnects, but i have also see examples where the client published data without a disconnect message sending after each sensor data publication. 
What is the best approach ?

Comment: As it stands this question is too broad to get a proper answer. Please read the guidelines on asking good questions - http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: but this is a exact question

Comment: "what is the best approach?" is very broad. It depends entirely on your situation.

Comment: What is the difference i mean if i publish every 2 seconds sensordata, should i send a DISCONNECT-Packet and then resend again via PUBLISH-Packet?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send sensor data frequently, try maintaining the connection. Otherwise you need to send keepalive message regularly.